# Inconsistent null attribute handling in ASP.NET MVC 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, html-helper

I have been trying to handle optional HTML `required` and `readonly` attributes in ASP.NET MVC 4. For my surprise, I found out that `null` attributes in HTML helpers are rendered as empty strings while they are removed completely in Razor (desired behavior).

For example, this code:

```
  @{ string disabled = null; string @readonly = null; }

  @Html.TextBox("t1", "Value", new { disabled, @readonly })
  <input type="text" name="t2" value="Value" disabled="@disabled" readonly="@(@readonly)" />
```

Renders:

```
  <input disabled="" id="t1" name="Txt1" readonly="" type="text" value="Value" />
  <input type="text" name="t2" value="Value" />
```

Basically what I want to know is:

- What is the reason behind these two different behaviors?
- Is there a way to get the same result using `Html.TexBox` without writing any custom code?

**EDIT**

This is not possible without writing a custom Html Helper, but there's a feature request for this on [CodePlex](https://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/workitem/476).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Html.TextBox()` behavior comes from code in `System.Web.Mvc.Html` that transforms a `RouteValueDictionary` of attributes into actual HTML.  (I believe that code is in `TagBuilder`)

The raw HTML tag behavior comes from a feature in the Razor v2 language parser that removes attributes in Razor markup that resolve to `null` at runtime.

Comment: Yeah, but still... one will expect a consistent handling of these cases throughout the platform. Is there a way to mimic similar behavior in Html.Helpers?

Comment: @Meryovi: Not that I know of (without modifying source).   You can open a feature request or pull request at http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/

Comment: I just found there is already a feature request there, thanks!